# Connotation behind "forking possibilites"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, connotations, semantic-roles

*"Every time you make a choice, a decision, the reality forks off into a new possibility. "* - The OA

What would you imagine under those words?

Does "forking" connote rather

1. with the process of [a path] splitting into two (a world in which a new reality arises whenever you make a decision)?

[image: growing tree]

2. with the state of a path having a junction (a world in which the universe just leads you from a decision to a decision)?

[image: choosing a path in a tree graph]

Comment: I don't see a whole lot of difference between Options 1 & 2. Sure, Option 1 is a bit more artistic, but Option 2 looks like an upside-down subset of Option 1.

Comment: @J.R. The difference is that in the first one, forking means we're talking magical paths that separate as you walk on them. The second one means it's about already given paths, from which we can only choose our favorite one.

Comment: The thing is, when you make a decision, you don't get the full tree. You do not take both forks, only one of them. So neither representation is accurate.   Maybe if it said "When you're confronted with a choice." instead of *make a choice*.  What you need is a decision-tine :) Only lightning takes both forks.

Comment: @Probably **bifurcation**?

Comment: @CookieMonster yes!

Comment: Religions have risen and fallen on this question; I think you might get better answers on Philosophy.SE, as this isn't something that's going to be universal across English speakers (and it's probably going to vary more by individual or belief system than linguistic group).

Comment: UPDATE :) I've expressed myself wrong. What I meant to ask was, whether "forking" connotes rather with the process of [a path] splitting into two or rather with the description of a path with a junction.

Comment: @Probably It can mean either, depending on the exact context. If you're talking about a literal path (e.g. a track through the woods, or a road), then a fork would simply be a single path becoming two separate paths with already defined onward courses (so B). If you're talking about a theory of infinite parallel universes, like in the quote, then the two paths after the fork don't have set paths, because they only exist after you actually make the decision.

Comment: @Antony_Grist So it can mean both of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would think of **A.**

A <sub>teeny tiny</sub> correction:

> Every time you make a choice, a decision, reality forks off into a new possibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's about opening up possibilities, rather than choosing a specific path out of pre-determined options. I don't know the series the quote comes from (but I 'know of it' and it's on my list of things to watch...) but from the context given, it means that you were on a "straight line" path (in a limited sense of what you are looking at) but then make a choice and it "branches out" from that path. Like when a new branch forms on a tree from the trunk you had already.

Out of your 2 options it is (A) but with the sense that all those "branches" of the tree don't exist already. They only come to exist when you explore a path by making a choice.

EDIT: I didn't get involved in the philosophical debates about this (in the comments) but do understand them -- but from the specific wording "Forks **off** into a **new** possibility" I would take it from context that a 'new' situation is being generated, that is "shooting off" (outwards) from the old one.